# How do I change the background in HTML when i click on an element?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a how drones work webpage for my DT class and Ive come across a road block.

As part of my assignment i wanted it so when a user clicks on the drop down menu it changes the background to an image related to that thing so for radio waves it would have a radio wave graph in the background etc.

Would anyone be able to help me with that I'm pretty sure it requires java from the research I've done. I have looked at 2 similar occurrences and haven't found anything that works.

Here's the code, it will look terrible because of the lack of CSS.

Also keep in mind you this is 1 of 7 instances where I'm using this code on a the same page.

```
<div class="docs-accordion-group accGroup">
  <div class="docs-accordion__title accTitle ">
    <span class="accordion__arr"></span>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="docs-accordion__link" style="font-weight: 700">
      Radio
      <script>
        // function name:
        function background_chg()
      </script>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="docs-accordion__panel accordion__panel accPanel">
    <div class="para">
      <div class="para" style="font: arial">
        <p1>A radio wave from the portion of the electromagnetic spectrum at lower frequencies than microwaves. The wavelengths of radio waves range from thousands of metres to 30 cm.</p1>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Java is in JavaScript ike Cat in Caterpillar

Comment: you should provide more info. Where is that dropdown menu and what did you try for this? It doesn't require java unless you are using spring boot as backend or using servlet-jsp or spring or any other java technology. If you are just trying to create a webpage with clicklisteners then it only needs javascript

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
<div class="docs-accordion-group accGroup">
  <div class="docs-accordion__title accTitle">
    <span class="accordion__arr"></span>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="docs-accordion__link" style="font-weight: 700" onclick="backgroundChange('radio')">
      Radio
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="docs-accordion__panel accordion__panel accPanel">
    <div class="para" id="radioContent">
      <div class="para" style="font: arial">
        <p>A radio wave is a portion of the electromagnetic spectrum at lower frequencies than microwaves. The wavelengths of radio waves range from thousands of meters to 30 cm.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
  function backgroundChange(option) {
    // Define an object that maps options to corresponding image URLs
    const imageUrls = {
      radio: 'url_to_radio_wave_image.png', // Replace 'url_to_radio_wave_image.png' with the actual URL of your image
      // Add other options and their image URLs here
      // For example:
      // microwaves: 'url_to_microwaves_image.png',
      // drones: 'url_to_drones_image.png',
    };

    // Get the content div element based on the option
    const contentDiv = document.getElementById(`${option}Content`);

    // Set the background image of the content div based on the option
    contentDiv.style.backgroundImage = imageUrls[option];
  }
</script>
```